Could someone tell me what this part of an A320 is called in English?
I'm trying to understand a French document about the A320.
It's talking about a dual-input situation.
It says this:

Devant le pilote ayant pris la priorité, sur la partie supérieure du
tableau de bord appelée bandeau, un voyant vert s'allume dans le
cas où l'autre manche n'est pas en position neutre, signifiant ainsi
que l'autre pilote tente d'agir sur son manche.

A rough translation is:

In front of the pilot who has taken priority, in the upper part of the
instrument panel called the banner (??), a green light is lit if
the other controller is not in neutral position, meaning that the
other pilot is attempting to operate their controller.

Normally I'd expect bandeau in French to be "banner". Or it might be "strip". It seems to be a panel or something above the main part of the instrument panel containing the PFD. Just like to know if there is a specific term used by A320 pilots.

I think it's talking about the glareshield panel. It has many controls and buttons, including the dual input indicator.

This line is called the glareshield
The side stick dual input indicators are present on a part of the glareshield panel called the glare wings. These are present on both sides of the glareshield panel.
They look like wings.

I think the document is about this indicator present in the A320 glareshield panel. It's for dual input.


The upper part of the instrument panel is called the glareshield. It extends further out from the panel and therefore protects the screens below from glare.
Here is an overview of the A320 Instrument Panel (on the Captain's side):

(Airbus A320 FCOM - Equipment - Flight Deck)
The side stick priority light your quote talks about is located on the glareshield:


1 SIDE STICK PRIORITY lt
Red arrow light:

comes on in front of the pilot losing authority
goes out if he has recovered his authority [...]

Green CAPT and F/O lights:

Both lights flash when the pilots move both sidesticks simultaneously and neither takes priority.
When a pilot has taken priority by pressing the takeover pushbutton and the other pilot's sidestick is not at neutral, the light in front of the pilot with priority lights up. It goes out when the other pilot returns his stick to the neutral position.


(Airbus A320 FCOM - Flight Controls - Controls and Indicators)
